# How to skip argument/parameter when copying files in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

1. `test.txt` contains 4 files with relative path:

   ```
   "brazil\206\tri\read.txt"
   "brazil\206\tri\log.i"
   "brazil\207\pass\prog.p"
   "brazil\206\bin\read.xml"
   ```

   Using following Batch script, I can copy all files:

   ```
   @echo off
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "test.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" ".\"
   ```
2. `test.txt` contains 4 files with relative path with parameters/arguments:

   ```
   "brazil\206\tri\read.txt" custom    
   "brazil\206\tri\log.i" standard
   "brazil\207\pass\prog.p" log
   "brazil\206\bin\read.xml" xml

   @echo off
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "test.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" ".\"
   ```

Getting an error, when copying; an error like too many parameters

How to skip/ignore parameter?

Here are examples:

```
"brazil\206\tri\read.txt" custom          #how to skip custom parameter/argument
"brazil\206\tri\log.i" standard           #how to skip standard parameter/argument
"brazil\207\pass\prog.p" log              #how to skip log parameter/argument
"brazil\206\bin\read.xml" xml             #how to skip xml parameter/argument
```

Comment: Use `for /f "tokens=1 delims= "`

Comment: Are there literally quotes inside the text file? brazil\206\tri\read.txt" custom

Comment: @DavidPostill: the only problem with using a space as a delimiter is if the relative path itself also has spaces like if: "brazil\206\tri\read this.txt" custom

Answer (score 0):

If the relative path in the text file doesn't contain any spaces in the relative path itself you could use the way suggested by DavidPostill and use a space as a delimiter:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('type "test.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" ".\"
```

If the relative path inside the text does contain spaces in the path itself or in the filename to be copied like in:

"brazil - Rio de Janeiro\206\tri\read file.txt" custom

You could use quotes as a delimiter:

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=^1^ delims^=^" %%a in ('type test.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" ".\"
```